# How to not show edges of light mask?

Tags: opengl, libgdx

I'm using this image for my light mask:

[image]

But in game the edges are visible, as seen here:

[image]

What do I change to stop this from happening? Is it a problem with the image or the way it is being rendered? My code looks like this:

```
frameBuffer.begin();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(CLEAR, CLEAR, CLEAR * 2, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE);
    batch.begin();

    // render lights
    currentMap.lightsController.render(batch);

    batch.end();

    frameBuffer.end();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // render map, entities, everything
    currentMap.render(camera, batch);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix().idt());
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ZERO, GL20.GL_SRC_COLOR);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture(), -1, 1, 2, -2);
    batch.end();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "edges"? Those dots from your screenshot or you don't like how gradient is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your texture itself. It's just not faded to complete darkness/black. On the edge of the texture the value (lightness) is still about 3%. Just rework your texture and make sure that your gradient is correct.